# What is the logic behind "if" statements? Drawing with for-loops

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, drawing

So I'm supposed to draw a mountain using a for-loop, using if statements to decide what character to use. This what I did initially.

```
for (int y = intMaxHeight; y >= 0; y--){
           for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
             double height = arr[x];
             
              if (y == 0){
                   System.out.print("-");
               } 
               
              if (((y - height) < 1) && ((y - height) > -1)){
                   System.out.print("^");
               } 
              
               if (y > height){
                   System.out.print(" ");
               }
              
               if ( y < height){
                   System.out.print(symbol);
               }       
           }
           System.out.println();
     }
```

This prints out a very ugly mountain
[image: This prints out a very ugly mountain]
Now, by adding "else" to the last three statements, the mountain looks like what it's supposed to, and I wonder why is that.
[image]

But the new problem is that the mountaintop symbol "^" will be printed twice sometimes, which is not supposed to happen. I tried switching the order of the if statement, but just like with the ugly mountain, it didn't change anything. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

It’s the way if/else statements work. In your current structure, they are all ifs. That means if the first statement is true, the code goes in and executes the block inside the statement. But it then goes and checks itself on all the other if statements too and if any turn out to be true, it will also enter and execute the code inside it.
When using if/else statements once an if block is entered none of the other blocks will be entered. So like the example above, if the first if statement is entered, then the rest of the else ifs don’t need to be checked.
The else or else if is only checked if the previous if fails

Comment: So that's my mistake. I thought java was going back to the beginning of the loop if one condition was satisfied.

Comment: @JavaScholar no it wouldn’t, unless you use the continue keyword in each statement, but I’d recommend doing if else statements

Comment: @CarlosLópez break would exit the loop while continue would move to the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your "top of the mountain" check covers the interval equal to nearly 2 vertical spaces:

```
((y - height) < 1) && ((y - height) > -1)
```

It would be easier to round `height` to `int`, and use its value with equality comparison:

```
long height = Math.round(arr[x]);
```

Now you can compare `height` to `y` directly, and print `^` when the two are equal to each other.

**Note:** A better way to check interval matches is with `Math.abs`, like this:

```
if (Math.abs(y - height) < 1) ...
```